# Transition rate matrix of a combined birth-death processes.

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process

If the transition rate matrix X of one birth-death process is defined by

\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda & \mu \\
\mu & -\lambda
\end{bmatrix}

and another transition rate matrix Y of a second birth-death process is

\begin{bmatrix}
-\alpha & \beta \\
\beta & -\alpha
\end{bmatrix}

And let $Z = X + Y$, is the transition rate matrix of $Z$ the following?

\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda - \alpha & \mu + \beta \\
\mu + \beta & -\lambda - \alpha
\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In birth-death processes, it is assumed that arrival times are Poisson and death times are exponential. Since the sum of two Poisson processes is another with $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$ we can safely say the arrival time of the new process is going to be Poisson with $\mu+ \beta$ in your question.

The departure time (death) is the minimum of the 2 departure times. Departure times are exponential and minimum of 2 exponential is also exponential with the sum of underlying two rates. Hence, you can say the departure time is $-\lambda -\alpha$ in your example.

Combining the two, we can say that the new added process is another birth/death with ($\mu+ \beta$, $-\lambda -\alpha$), so the transition rate matrix you gave is correct.